# dplyr use filter only if a variable exists

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working towards creating a Shiny App with interactive selections.
IF an area has been selected, then I would like to filter my data based on that.  However, IF no Area has been selected then I do not whish to filter.

I have read a few related posts but none seem to answer my question.

Here are a few of my attempts.  All resulting in an error message

```
 top<-test %>%
   filter(date > start_date & date < end_date ) %>%
   filter(if (exists(selected_Area))Area==selected_Area else TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(Quarter=quarter(date, type = "date_first", fiscal_start = 11)) %>%
   mutate(Year=year(date))%>%
   # getting the top products sold over that timeframe
   group_by(Area,Main_Category,Sub_Category,Sample,Analyte,Isolation_Method) %>%
   summarise(sum_products_grouped=sum(Products_sold)) %>%
   unite(group_name,Sub_Category,Sample,Analyte,Isolation_Method) %>%
    top_n(top_numb,sum_products_grouped)
```

I was also thinking something like this, but the syntax is incorrect.

```
  if (exists(selected_Area)) {
         filter(Area==selected_Area) %>% }
```

Here is the data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(PID = c(233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 
233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 
6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 
6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6880L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 
6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 
6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 
6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L, 6507L
), Name = c("Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", 
"Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", 
"Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", 
"Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", "Genomic DNA Isolation Kit", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Slurry Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", "FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)", 
"FBS Exosome Depletion Kit I (Column Format)"), Category = c("DNA Kits", 
"DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", 
"DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "DNA Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits", 
"Multi-Analyte Kits", "Multi-Analyte Kits"), Area = c("Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", "Isolation_and_Purification", 
"Isolation_and_Purification"), Main_Category = c("DNA kits", 
"DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", 
"DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", "DNA kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", "exosome kits", 
"exosome kits", "exosome kits"), Sub_Category = c("DNA Isolation", 
"DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", 
"DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", 
"DNA Isolation", "DNA Isolation", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", "Exosome clean-up", 
"Exosome clean-up"), Sample_Category = c("multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Sample = c("multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", "multi-sample", 
"multi-sample", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", 
"FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", 
"FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", 
"FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", 
"FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", 
"FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS", "FBS"), Analyte = c("totDNA", 
"totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", 
"totDNA", "totDNA", "totDNA", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Sample_Volume = c("micro", 
"micro", "micro", "micro", "micro", "micro", "micro", "micro", 
"micro", "micro", "micro", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", 
"maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi", "maxi"), Isolation_Method = c("spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", 
"slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", 
"slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", "slurry", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", 
"spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column", "spin column"
), Product_Size = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), date = structure(c(18440, 
18470, 18501, 18532, 18562, 18593, 18623, 18654, 18685, 18713, 
18744, 19050, 19078, 19109, 19139, 19170, 19200, 19231, 19262, 
19292, 19323, 19353, 19384, 19415, 19443, 19474, 19504, 19535, 
19565, 19596, 19627, 19657, 17862, 17892, 17923, 17954, 17982, 
18013, 18043, 18074, 18104, 18135, 18166, 18196, 18227, 18257, 
18288, 18319, 18348, 18379, 18409, 18440, 18470, 18501, 18532, 
18562, 18593, 18623, 18654, 18685, 18713, 18744), class = "Date"), 
    Products_sold = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: use `%>% { if (exists('selected_Area', .)) filter(., Area==selected_Area) else .} %>%`

Comment: you could always just have a drop down box of the columns which are available...your title and your question body seem to stand in opposition to one another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a small helper function, `filter_if_selected`.

````
filter_if_selected <- function(data, selected){
  if(is.null(selected)) return(data) # or, if needed. replace is.null() with exists()
  dplyr::filter(data, Area == selected)
}

top<-test %>%
  filter(date > start_date & date < end_date ) %>%
  filter_if_selected(selected_Area) %>%
  mutate(Quarter=quarter(date, type = "date_first", fiscal_start = 11)) %>%
  mutate(Year=year(date))%>%
  # getting the top products sold over that timeframe
  group_by(Area,Main_Category,Sub_Category,Sample,Analyte,Isolation_Method) %>%
  summarise(sum_products_grouped=sum(Products_sold)) %>%
  unite(group_name,Sub_Category,Sample,Analyte,Isolation_Method) %>%
  top_n(top_numb,sum_products_grouped)```
````

Comment: Note that `selected` is not null. It either exists or does not. thereby using `is.null` is incorrect

Comment: I inferred that the OP will use the selected_Area variable to filter in a shiny app based on if a variable is selected, and thus that it will show up (or not) in the variable selected_Area. In such a case, is.null is probably correct. But maybe that is a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account the pipe, use the command below:

```
... %>% 
 { if (exists('selected_Area')) filter(., Area == selected_Area) 
   else .} %>%
...
```

eg:
compare the following

```
 iris %>%
   { if (exists('Species', .)) head(.)
     else NA
   }
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

 iris %>%
   { if (exists('Species2', .)) head(.)
     else NA
   }
 [1] NA
```

Comment: Note for people who care- this won't work with the native pipe `|>` (or, at least, I haven't been able to get their equivalent to it working in my code)

Comment: @Mark with the native pipe, use an anonymous function. It should work the same

Comment: @Mark isnt this inline? `iris |>(\(x)if(exists('Species1', x)) head(x) else NA)()`? Not sure what you mean

Comment: ah I didn't realise you could use anonymouse functions in that way! thank you for sharing that :-)

Comment: Note that the variable selected_Area is not in the data frame that the OP provided, and is probably a separate variable. In that case you should change the if statement to `if (exists('Species1')) head(.)`

Comment: @LeonSamson thats incorrect. `mtcars` is the dataset, the dataset itself exists, probably just write `if exists(variable)` instead of useing `if exists(variable, in_dataset)`

Comment: It is not incorrect just maybe not the best example. I meant to change `mtcars` for the variable in question.

Comment: yes sorry to clarify, selected_Area  is a separate variable.